# Java List contains method

Tags: java, algorithm, list, arraylist

I was searching through the java ArrayList source code to see what happens when I convert the list to a array. 
I came across the method contains which I've used allot and know about and my first reaction to the method was, what sort of algorithm do the contains method use.

```
 public boolean contains(Object o) {
   return indexOf(o) >= 0;
 } 

 public int indexOf(Object o) {
  if (o == null) {
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (elementData[i]==null)
          return i;
  } else {
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
          return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

The code above extracted from the source code shows ArrayLists are using the sequential search.
I see so many people myself included using the contains method.
I think this is a good example where people need to know there Algorithms and Java collections. When you sit with a list which has a large number of items and you call the contains method each time when you use the application it can become a problem.

One of the improvements I can think about is to use a binary search. 
Only if the items are sorted.
So you need either to order the items when they are added/queried from the database or when not using the db order with start-up of the application.

Is it better to use a different collection for the specific scenario or do I search the ArrayList using one of the util classes?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask]. Hint: SO is not a discussion forum, and you haven't asked a specific question, so this post is likely to get closed as "Not a real question".

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: My opinion: if you have a huge list where the performance starts to hurt, you're doing something wrong already.

Comment: Good reasoning, but the List interface, and the ArrayList implementation of it however does not tell anything about the ordering of its elements. Why should it use a hidden feature like that? If there was a SortedList interface, and their implementation, it would surely have an efficient search algorythm for contains...
Also `order with start-up of the application`: how would zou hndle lists coming from other sources you have no control about? Order with each new item? That sounds like quite an overhead with regards to the usual usage of the Lists...

Comment: See `Arrays.binarySearch(...)`

Comment: Use `HashSet` data structure it is only O(1) for searching. List is good for iteration and maintaining the order in which thing are added, if you sort the list you void the ordering.

Comment: @ShivamKalra not every set is `O(1)`. A tree set is `O(log n)`.

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks! I changed to hashset :)

Comment: I've done a couple of tests. HashSet contains method searches faster than a ArrayList contains method. Arrays.binarySearch takes almost the same time as the ArrayList contains method. Arrays.binarySearch needs to be sorted, it breaks if the array is not sorted. You also need to convert to list to array first before using Arrays.binarySearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different containers offer different performance guarantees and different space-time tradeoffs.

My advice is therefore to:

1. study data structures;
2. study the container library that you're using.

This will help you make informed choices with regards to which container to use, and how best to use it.

Comment: Binary search cannot be default because not all lists are sorted and not all lists contain Comparable elements. If your list does, surely calling contains(..) on large arrays is suboptimal. You should use Collections.binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key) instead.